# The existense of dynamic objects in qml

Tags: qt, qml

I'm creating several dynamic objects in my application using Qt - qml language, here is my code:

```
    var c = null
    c = Qt.createComponent("Lines.qml")
    var k = c.createObject(gameCanvas)
    k.height = 1
    k.width = grid.spacing
    k.x = image1.x + image1.width
    k.y = image1.y + image1.height / 2
```

here is my code at Lines.qml file:

```
Rectangle {

    property alias col: stayrec5.color
    height: 3
    width: 3

Rectangle {

    id: stayrec5
    x: 0
    y: 0
    color: "brown"
    height: parent.height
    smooth: true
    width: parent.width

    }

}
```

is there a way giving a random x,y coordinates to decide if one of the dynamic objects created previously exists at the same x or y coordinate, for e.x is there a function that i can pass to it the dynamic object (in my case `k` ) to know whether it exists at the same randomly given x or y coordinate or even both ?, Any ideas would be appreciated

Comment: You are using Qml wrong. Qml is a declarative language, not an imperative language, you should say what you want, not how to make it. You should probably generate a model (like a list of (x,y) coordinates) and then build a view from that in QML.

Comment: You give an example of what you tried which is good, but you should also always try to give an explanation of what problem you are trying to solve, independent of what partial solution you have. In this case, I think your approach is wrong. Qml can probably be used to do what you want very efficiently but not this way. Can you explain what you want to do in the end ?

Comment: can i store my dynamic objects (k's) in an array & search for them later on using a for loop

Comment: Can you use a hammer and a screw driver to pierce your walls ? maybe. Would it be better to use a powerdrill ? Probably. Can you please explain in two sentences what you want as a final result ? I think your approach is not the right one (as in not QML style)